# How can i calculate appState background time and appState foreground(active) state time in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to calculate the time(in seconds) when my app is in background and also the time when it is in foreground. How can I calculate background state time and foreground state time in react-native?

Comment: Use the `change` listener in [`AppState`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) and define state variables.

Comment: But how do I calculate the time of the appState?

Comment: @codekaizer can you provide a sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [codekaizer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8012206/codekaizer), you can use the [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) change listener to implement this.

Add a listener to `change` event as explained in the docs. When the app goes into `inactive` or `background` state save the timestamp to some local storage like [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage) or global state management tool like [redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Generate another timestamp on `active` state and compare both timestamps to get the `background/foreground` time of app.